# Group by query results differently depending on server

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-order-by

I have two tables I want to join on one attribute (Sensor_id). Then I want to GROUP BY on the same attribute but I need the result is ORDER BY Timestamp DESC attribute. So I used a subquery to first ORDER BY Timestamp DESC and then the outer query will GROUP BY Sensor_id 

First table: Sensors_colocation

```
=========================================================================================
| Sensor_id | Sensor_longitude | Sensor_latitude | Paese | Pseudonimo | limit1 | limit2 |
=========================================================================================
```

Second table: log

```
===========================================
| Id | Mac_reali | Mac_random | Timestamp |
===========================================
```

Using

```
SELECT * FROM log AS L JOIN Sensors_colocation AS S ON L.Id = S.Sensor_id ORDER BY L.Id ASC, L.Timestamp DESC
```

I get what I want on every of the two servers I have.
The problem is when I perform the full query

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM log AS L JOIN Sensors_colocation AS S ON L.Id = S.Sensor_id 
    ORDER BY L.Id ASC, L.Timestamp DESC) AS temp
GROUP BY temp.Id
```

on one server I get the results sorted by Timestamp DESC and grouped by Id. On the other server (that has the same structure but different data) I get the results sorted by Timestamp ASC and grouped by Id. I don't understand why if I use a subquery the ORDER BY I have in my inner query is not considered. 
Can you help me?

EDIT: My goal is to have all the attributes of the joined tables but only the last entry speaking of Timestamp of every Id.

EDIT2:

Not working:

```
10.1.41-MariaDB-0+deb9u1

CREATE TABLE `log` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Mac_reali` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Mac_random` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ALTER TABLE `log`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Id`,`Timestamp`);

CREATE TABLE `Sensors_colocation` (
  `Sensor_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Sensor_longitude` decimal(7,6) NOT NULL,
  `Sensor_latitude` decimal(8,6) NOT NULL,
  `Paese` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Pseudonimo` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `limit1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `limit2` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ALTER TABLE `Sensors_colocation`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Sensor_id`);
```

Working:

```
5.6.33-log


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Mac_reali` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Mac_random` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`,`Timestamp`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Sensors_colocation` (
  `Sensor_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Sensor_longitude` decimal(7,6) NOT NULL,
  `Sensor_latitude` decimal(8,6) NOT NULL,
  `Paese` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Pseudonimo` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `limit1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `limit2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Sensor_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

EDIT3:
Consider the output of inner query (I do not write some attributes that we don't need)

```
Id | Mac_reali | Timestamp | Sensor_id | Pseudonimo

1 | 30 | "2019-09-29 17:27:33" | 1 | Manarola(Stazione)
1 | 23 | "2019-09-29 17:25:33" | 1 | Manarola(Stazione)
1 | 57 | "2019-09-29 17:23:33" | 1 | Manarola(Stazione)
2 | 12 | "2019-09-29 17:28:42" | 2 | Vernazza(Stazione)
2 | 33 | "2019-09-29 17:26:42" | 2 | Vernazza(Stazione)
2 | 12 | "2019-09-29 17:24:42" | 2 | Vernazza(Stazione)
3 | 23 | "2019-09-29 17:33:42" | 3 | Monterosso(Stazione)
3 | 17 | "2019-09-29 17:31:42" | 3 | Monterosso(Stazione)
3 | 16 | "2019-09-29 17:29:42" | 3 | Monterosso(Stazione)
```

From the "working" server, from the outer query I get

```
Id | Mac_reali | Timestamp | Sensor_id | Pseudonimo

1 | 30 | "2019-09-29 17:27:33" | 1 | Manarola(Stazione)
2 | 12 | "2019-09-29 17:28:42" | 2 | Vernazza(Stazione)
3 | 23 | "2019-09-29 17:33:42" | 3 | Monterosso(Stazione)
```

From the "not working" server I get the opposite speaking of Timestamp (as if ORDER BY is ignored)

```
Id | Mac_reali | Timestamp | Sensor_id | Pseudonimo

1 | 57 | "2019-09-29 17:23:33" | 1 | Manarola(Stazione)
2 | 12 | "2019-09-29 17:24:42" | 2 | Vernazza(Stazione)
3 | 16 | "2019-09-29 17:29:42" | 3 | Monterosso(Stazione)
```

Comment: Your main problem is that you are playing russian roulette when using `GROUP BY` ANSI/ISO SQL standard rules invalid as explained n the MySQL [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: You have `SELECT *` and `GROUP BY`.  That is incoherent.  Please explain the logic you want to implement and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: ... @GordonLinoff 's statement is not totally correct as `SELECT * .. GROUP BY ...` can be valid by [functional dependence](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f4Kz6EYNRTiRFKC6WQx2Kf/1) vs [non key usage/functional dependence](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f4Kz6EYNRTiRFKC6WQx2Kf/2).. But we need table structures and MySQL version and sql_mode to verivy if functional dependence exception rules are valid and can be trusted here as the manual explains when it is detected correctly ..

Comment: For example data and expected results .. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)  .. To provide MySQL version -> `SELECT VERSION()`  .. To provide table structures -> `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`  ... To provide sql_mode -> `SELECT @@sql_mode;`

Comment: @RaymondNijland added version and table structures. I'll edit with a short example of expected result

Comment: did you test @GMB 's first query if it works and fetches the correct results on both servers ... But ideally you need to use the **same** RDMS vendor and major/minor version meaning local and production should both be running `MySQL 5.6.33-log`  or `10.1.41-MariaDB-0+deb9u1` .. don't mix things up as it is asking for trouble not even major versions in the same RDMS product like MySQL 5.6 or MySQL 5.7..

Comment: @RaymondNijland the problem is that I used the db on online hosting site untill I moved all the tables on the new MariaDB of my University. I cannot control versions and the working server I don't use it anymore. GMB first query make phpmyadmin freeze.

Comment: @RaymondNijland added an example of output

Answer (score 1):

> My goal is to have all the attributes of the joined tables but only the last entry speaking of Timestamp of every Id.

Consider this approach that uses a correlated subquery to ensure that there is no other `log` record for the same `id` with a greater `timestamp`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM log l
INNER JOIN sensors_colocation s ON l.id = s.sensor_id 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM log l1
    WHERE l1.id = l.id AND l1.timestamp > l.timestamp
)
ORDER BY l.id ASC, l.timestamp DESC
```

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can get the same result by using window function `ROW_NUMBER()` to rank records by descending timestamp within groups of records having the same `id`, and then filtering on the top record per group:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        l.*, 
        s.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY l.id ORDER BY l.timestamp DESC) rn
    FROM log l
    INNER JOIN sensors_colocation s ON l.id = s.sensor_id 
) x
WHERE rn = 1
```

Note: for performance, you need an index on `log(id, timestamp)`.

Comment: Also `ORDER BY l.id ASC, l.timestamp DESC` in the first query feels like it should be `ORDER BY l.timestamp DESC, l.id ASC/DESC` instead by the way

Comment: @cristina You need indexes (seems your dataset is big). Define a composite index `(id, timestamp)` on table `log`